# Wrong Pages In sitemap.xml of magento

Tags: magento, seo

How to solve error of Wrong Pages found error in sitemap.xml of Magento? After i set "No" value in "Use Categories Path for Product URLs"...

Comment: try generating xml again from backend

Answer (score 2):

```
It seems from your question that earlier you were having some urls for which path is now changed, thus you want earlier URL to be removed. If this is the case then you there are several option:-

Firstly google itself remove url not found after certain search.

Secondly you can use Google remove url tool(https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/url-removal), only if you have access of webmaster tool.

Thirdly add the url in robot.txt so that they are no more indexed by Google.

Hope this answers your question
```